# Database Connection UI not showing when called inside a function

Tags: r, odbc

I am using RStudio Server and ODBC to connect to a redshift database. I can connect easily using:

```
  conn <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), Driver="redshift", 
                        Server = SERVER_URL,
                        Port = "5439",
                        Database = DB_NAME,
                        PWD = PASSWORD,
                        UID = CREDENTIALS,
                        timeout = 10,
                        Trusted_Connection = "True")
```

When connected in shows up in the sidebar "connections" where I have an UI to look through the database. That is exactly what i want.

The problem is that if i call the same code inside a function, then I get the database connection but no UI?!? How do i get the UI to appear when calling this code from inside a function?

C

```
onnection_odbc_profile <- function(INPUT){
    conn <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), Driver="redshift", 
                        Server = SERVER_URL,
                        Port = "5439",
                        Database = DB_NAME,
                        PWD = PASSWORD,
                        UID = CREDENTIALS,
                        timeout = 10,
                        Trusted_Connection = "True")
     return(conn)
}
```

I think the issue is that the connection pane only gets updated when the code is run at top-level. Is there any way to force a line of code in a function to run at top-level (or directly in the console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding:

```
code <- c(match.call())   # This saves what was typed into R
  odbc:::on_connection_opened(conn, paste(c(paste("con <-", gsub(", ", ",\n\t", code))), collapse = "\n"))
```